# Wordpress: Automatically show only one post when clicked on title

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm searching for a solution for about 4 hours, I can't(don't want) invest no more time in this specific problem.
My issue is that I want to get wordpress fully working.
(Almost) Everything is fine: I can show all posts or only a defined number, but I can't figure out how to show only THE POST on which the user clicked (on either the title or read-more)
The $_GET-data that is shown is 'p' => that shows the post-id (e.g 35,11,etc..)

HERE A QUICK EXAMPLE : ( I TOOK THE PART THAT DIDN'T WORK OUT)

```
echo $_GET['p'].'<br>';
                if(!isset($_GET['p'])) :
                    $myposts = get_posts();
                else :
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'offset'=> $_GET["p"]);
                    $myposts = query_posts($args);
                endif;
                $index = 0;
                foreach($myposts as $post) :
                    setup_postdata($post);
                    ?>
                    <div class="article">
                        <p class="title">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </p>
                        <span class="date-block">
                            <p class="day"><?php the_time('j'); ?></p>
                            <p class="year"><?php the_time('Y'); ?></p>             
                            <p class="month"><?php the_time('F'); ?></p>
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                    endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
```

Please help me,I think I gave you all the information needed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY I GOT IT WORKING:
It's actually simple (as always it's harder to find out..)
For others having the same issue, here's the solution :

```
$post_id = $_GET['p'];
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
the_title();
echo $queried_post->post_content;
$posttags = get_the_tags($post_id);
if ($posttags)
foreach($posttags as $tag)
echo $tag->name;
```

Comment: Please do not include signatures in your posts; especially ones which contain self-promotional links. You may put that sort of thing in your profile.